# Power BI Custom Column with value from next row

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to make a custom column in Power BI with the value in the column equal to the value in the next row from another column. The value I am trying to copy is a time/date value and I am unsure of the DAX formula that I should be using to get create the column with.

[image]

Above is a snippet of the current columns.
So in the first row of the new column I would like to see the value from the second row of the Time column and so on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no "previous line" or "next line" concept in DAX. There must be a sorting criteria. Can we assume that by "next row" you mean the row with the lowest time greater than the current one?

Comment: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-to-shift-down-1-row-for-only-1-column-in-M/m-p/380758/highlight/true#M173177